# Method to do Feature Agglomeration/summation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, bioinformatics, word-frequency

I.E - Combining least frequent or informative bigram frequency counts together.

E.G  - If I have frequency counts of letter pairs for a sequence, what's a good way to merge similar features together. (For example: "KR" and "RK" into a single feature and so on, or combining all the pairs with a count of 0 together..).

I know scikit learn has something called "ward's agglomerative clustering", but that seems aimed at visual data/pixels, and i'm interested in text data (*Protein sequences and bioinformatics*). I'd rather avoid clustering if there's a more direct method for concatenating the features together.  (I lack background, and haven't done clustering before, and analysis of the features is important to us).
Thanks!

Comment: Almost nothing in scikit-learn is aimed at visual data -- use a bag of words vectorizer, and Ward clustering should work. (Not saying it's actually a good idea, but then I've never tried.)

Comment: How does this work though? Clustering - clusters samples, not features/variables..?

Comment: If you regard a set of samples as a matrix `X` (as scikit-learn does), then you can transpose that matrix to swap the role of features and samples. I.e. in the text case, you cluster terms by the documents they occur in, rather than documents by the terms that occur in them.

Comment: I kind of think that what you really should be looking at is dimensionality reduction, usually done by matrix decomposition http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html

Comment: I'll be doing dimension reduction as well, but I'm implementing other features also - I want to agglomerate these features on their own, then use the results as a new, more compact set of features (that will be added to others).